# Javascript/jquery age verification popup for magento

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, verification

Okay, so I tried to integrate [this datepicker](http://jquerywall.com/demo-age-verification-jquery-ui-datepicker/) to my magento page for the purpose of age verification.

I have successfully added the required CSS and jQuery script files to the head section of my magento page but I can't figure out where to add the html.

The package source is available [here](http://jquerywall.com/jquery-download/age-verification-jquery-ui-datepicker.zip) along with the html and javascript files. 
I want to modify it so that when a person is over 18, they stay on the page and if not, they get redirected to google.com.

Can't get this working because I am not sure how to add the index.html file's code to my magento page. I'd really appreciate some help.

Or is there an alternate (simpler) way to put 'Age verification' WITH cookies, without using PHP script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following script for this validation may be it's help you.

```
<script>
function check_dob()
{
    var month = document.getElementById('month').value;
    var day = document.getElementById('day').value;
    var year = document.getElementById('year').value;
    var dbDate = year+'-'+month+'-'+day;
    var today = new Date();
    var birthDate = new Date(dbDate);
    var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
    var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
    age--;
    }

    if(age<=20)
    {
        alert("You are under "+age+" Year")
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put some/all of the html into your template, probably somewhere where it will be on every page.  e.g. /app/design/frontend/*package*/_theme_/template/page/html/header.phtml

Comment: Hello Jared, thanks for replying. I added the html of the index.html file from the package to header.phtml, but it doesn't work.

Can you suggest a better way to put an age gate to magento?

Comment: "It didn't work" is not enough for me to help.  Why didn't it work.  Is it possible it didn't have the JS or CSS include?  This package seems fine (provided it meeds whatever regulation standards you need to). Otherwise you would have to use PHP etc.

Comment: Here's what I did:
I copied the entire code from d index.html file from the package and pasted it 2 the header.phtml like you said (cuz i want it 2 appear on every page). 

NEXT

I deleted the old path references for the required .js and .css files in the copied code and added new path references of .js and .css files (which i have saved locally on my server) to the page.xml file located at 
 "/app/design/frontend/default/MY_THEME/layout/
like this:
"<action method="addJs"><script>ageverification/jquery.cookie.js</script></action>"
Now i see the code in the page source, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Here is an example of what i am trying to achieve: [johnsoncreeksmokejuice.com](http://www.johnsoncreeksmokejuice.com/)

Comment: Can you post a link to your testing site (perhaps contact me through my website since I don't know how to private message in SO).  My guess would be that you didn't put the JS in the right folder or something so it isn't being included.  (i.e. /skin/frontend/_package/_theme_/ageverification/jquery.cookie.js)  Or you don't have a compatible version of jQuery loading before it.

Comment: Message sent on your website. Really appreciate your help :)